# Can two Pythagorean triples have the same product?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I'm writing a program to search for Pythagorean triples, and I want to decrease the search-time as much as possible (obviously).

There's a method that will decrease the search-time drastically, if only it could be proven that no two Pythagorean triples will have the exact product of multiplying their terms.

For example, `[3, 4, 5]` and `[15, 20, 25]`. Indeed, `3 x 4 x 5` is not equal to `15 x 20 x 25`. But could this be proven for **all** Pythagorean triples?

Comment: Why search when there is a parametrization See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: Because I want to find **all** of the Pythagorean triples between say N and M. I don't want to generate **any** triples.

Comment: By the way, all products of Pythagorean triples are necessarily divisible by 60. This may benefit your method.

Comment: Surely the parametric form can be adapted to generate all the solutions in a range, whatever it is one means by range (hypotenuse maybe?).

Comment: @Magma That won't benefit the method, but thanks anyway. This may come in handy in the future. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments of [the OEIS sequence listing all these products](https://oeis.org/A057096), this is an open problem.

Comment: Welp, time to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\qquad A=m^2-n^2\qquad B=2mn\qquad C=m^2+n^2\qquad$  the product is
$$P=(m^2-n^2)\times2mn\times(m^2+n^2)\quad=2m^5n-2mn^5\quad=2mn(m-n)(m+n)(m^2+n^2)$$

The [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) states that every integer greater than $1$ is either prime or the unique product prime factors. Therefore, no $2$ Pythagorean triples can have the same product.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful but it suggests that trying to find two equal products is too much of a hassle anyway, so I'm not really interested anymore; Especially that I found another way to achieve (almost) the same level of optimization. thanks though :)