# How to prove no two Pythagorean triples have the same product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, galois-theory, pythagorean-triples

In reference to a [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283987/can-two-pythagorean-triples-have-the-same-product), I "think" that no $2$-or-more Pythagoean triples have the same product of $A\times  B\times C$ but I don't know how to prove it.  All primitive triples are unique in their values of ABC. There are an infinite number of these products. None appear to be the same. How do I prove that, for all combinations of $m,n$,

$2m_1n_1(m_1^2-n_1^2)(m_1^2+n_1^2)\ne 2m_2n_2(m_2^2-n_2^2)(m_2^2+n_2^2)?$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can two Pythagorean triples have the same product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283987/can-two-pythagorean-triples-have-the-same-product)

Comment: This turns out to be an open problem!!

Comment: @ SL_MathGuy I reference the link you provided in my question.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $m_1+n_1$ not $m_1+m_1$?

Comment: @QC_QAOA . Thanks for pointing out the OP error.

Comment: unless the scaled products are coprime, you might capitalize on the scaling of sides multiplying by the cube of the scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pythagorean triples are integers and integers have a unique prime factorization.

Every primitive pythagorean triple contains 3 coprimes. If 2 triples had the same product, this would probably violate the prime factorization thrm.

Comment: The two triples $(13, 33, 35)$ and $(11, 21, 65)$ both consist of three pairwise coprime integers, but they have the same product. So your argument is unfortunately flawed.